# AttributeError during Django-rest-framework tutorial 4: authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm following the django-rest-framework tutorial and I can't figure out what is happening here.

I've created a UserSerializer class with a snippets attribute and I did all the imports

```
#--!-coding: utf-8
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style', 'owner')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

Then I've created the UserList and the UserDetails views:

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and I've follow the tutorial pretty much, but when I try to access one of the users endpoints I got an AttributeError

```
AttributeError at /users/

'User' object has no attribute 'snippets'
```

I am using django 1.7.5 and django-rest-framework 3.0.5

I don't know if it is a problem for this specific version.

EDIT:

This is my Models:

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    highlighted = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Usa o a biblioteca pygments para criar um representacao HTML com destaque do snippet
        """
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)
        linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False
        options = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(style=self.style, linenos=linenos, full=True, **options)
        self.highlighted = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)
        super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Does the `User` model have a `snippets` field by default?

Comment: No, but there is a snippet_set because of the Foreignkey, @mattm.

Comment: @Bakuriu , I am following the tutorial, all right? I added a snippets field on my UserSerializer class, and that is what I am using. I've used the generics.ListAPIView to make the views, so it should work.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations; manage.py migrate` after adding the snippet foreign key?

Comment: yes, I have, @Alexander

Comment: @FernandoFreitasAlves how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I've done exactly as the only answer here says... I just have forgotten to add the owner as a foreign key in my snippets model with a related name snippet @null pointer

Comment: I'm doing exactly same but still getting same error

Comment: Did you run make migrations and migrate after doing that? @null pointer

Comment: yes I did..but it said *No migrations to apply*

Comment: ooops my bad.. didn't add those fields in models.py.. your question saved me

Comment: Good, I've committed the same mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your snippets model, you need to add a related name to your owner field.

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
```